# FirestoreRecyclerOptions. The query requires an index error, when no index needed. Only when I use orderBy

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using Firestore database, and FirebaseUI to load the results into a recycler view in android kotlin. I am experiencing something weird.

I understand the error "The query requires an index", when making too many different requests over different fields. However, I understand you can make many requests, whereEqualTo, together with one request orderBy. Now, when I make this request myself (not using FirestoreRecyclerOptions). I have no problem and it works great.

However when I use the request with FirestoreRecyclerOptions, for example like this:

```
 var querySearch = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
            .collection(DB_DEALS_COLLECTION).document(departureCountry.toString()).collection(DB_DEALS_SUB_COLLECTION)
            .whereEqualTo(FILTER_FIELD_APR, true)
            .whereEqualTo(FILTER_FIELD_AUG, true)
            .whereEqualTo(FILTER_FIELD_DEC, true)
            .orderBy(FILTER_FIELD_TIMESTAMP, Query.Direction.DESCENDING).limit(15)

        val options = FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<Deal>().setQuery(querySearch, Deal::class.java).build()
```

I get this error:

[`Firestore]: Listen for Query(target=Query(deals_collection/USA/deals where monthApr == true and monthAug == true and monthDec == true order by -timestamp, -__name__);limitType=LIMIT_TO_FIRST) failed: Status{code=FAILED_PRECONDITION, description=The query requires an index.`

Now, two things are weird:
1. Actually the correct results show in my recyclerview, I think, so far as I have checked. But I'm worrying why I'm getting this message, and I don't want to have incorrect results in the future.
2. WHen I click on the link in the console to add the index, I get this message in the Firestore console to add: I have to make a composite index with these fields:

```
monthApr Ascending 
monthAug Ascending 
monthDec Ascending 
timestamp Descending
```

Now I never wanted these fields ascending, only the timestamp?

Note: This only happens when I include:

```
.orderBy(FILTER_FIELD_TIMESTAMP,
```

Also in the console I see, `limitType=LIMIT_TO_FIRST`. Also i see, `-__name__` . What are these, I never set them!

I hope my problem is clear, I'm a bit confused with all this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If your query does require an index, you should be able to create it easily by overridding [the error callback](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/firestore/src/main/java/com/firebase/ui/firestore/FirestoreRecyclerAdapter.java#L152) of the `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter`:

```
FirestoreRecyclerAdapter adapter = new FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<T, H>(options) {
   // ... 

    @Override
    public void onError(@NonNull FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
        Log.w(TAG, "onError", e);
    }
};
```

Then in your logcat you will see the full error which will include a link you can click to automatically create the missing index.

As for your other questions:

- Did you create your data from the same device?  If so that would explain why you're seeing data in the `RecyclerView` despite the error.  It's coming from the offline cache which does not use indexes.
- `.limit(15)` is a less verbose way of saying `.limitToFirst(15)`.  So you can ignore `limitType=LIMIT_TO_FIRST`.
- `__name__` is a special reserved field for the Document ID.  Every single query you do is ordered by `__name__` at the end, that way you always get results in the same order even if there is a tie on your other `orderBy` clauses.

Comment: Thanks. I already followed the link, as I said in the question. The problem is that each different query needs a new link to fix it up. I still don't know why these queries need an index?

Comment: Every query in Cloud Firestore must hit an index.  Some simple indexes are built in (whereEqualTo or orderBy on a single field) others must be created.

It is true that you will have to create many indexes if you have many different combinations.

Comment: But I explained in my question, that the field queries that I am using do not require indexes to be created. Only when I do the query with the Firebase Adapter I get the error.

Comment: I don't think that's true, have you tried looking for errors in your queries outside of FirebaseUI? There is no difference between a query that uses the adapter and one does not (context: I wrote the adapters).

Comment: I make the query outside the adapter and I have no error!

Comment: Can you do a `.get()` on the query (without involving FirebaseUI) instead of adding a listener and make sure it still succeeds?

Comment: Thats what I'm doing, and it succeeds

Comment: Ok please file an issue on the FirebaseUI-Android repository in that case.